# Implement Scroll Into View onPress on specific screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, rxjs, scrollview, js-scrollintoview

I'm trying to implement my code day by day by updating myself to right solution..
In below code I want to implement onPress button Screen redirection on same window with scrollview as it mention in code, there is a Two Screen A and Screen B, and above there is Two buttons when I click on any of the button at that time I want action to scroll to that screen..

how can I do this using **Scroll Into View Library**

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scroll-into-view

here is perfectly shown how I really want to make it..

> https://vix.digital/blog/technology/react-native-scroll-to/
>
> https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2ad769c6de7d3abf09f112361a0b07b38a54cb810774e332dfe28f6a95a9399b/68747470733a2f2f6d656469612e67697068792e636f6d2f6d656469612f505054525a52587a4846664f5756706f67762f67697068792e676966

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {
  Dimensions,
  RefreshControl,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Button from '../custom-components/Button'

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Button
              title="ScreenA"
              stylebtn={styles.btns}
              stylebtntitle={styles.btnsTxt}
              onPress={screenA}
            />
            <Button
              title="ScreenB"
              stylebtn={styles.btns}
              stylebtntitle={styles.btnsTxt}
              onPress={ScreenB}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          <ScreenA style={styles.screen}/>
          <ScreenB style={styles.screen}/>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. What have you tried and what errors did you run into. The library documentation also contains an example of how to use it to implement exactly what you need. Are you asking how to do it without the library ?

Comment: https://vix.digital/blog/technology/react-native-scroll-to/ check this link I want to make like this,  like I done this but its not working properly as expected its changed height wise @sushrut619